# Is there any way to embed a QWidget inside a QQmlApplicationEngine or QQuickView?

Tags: qt, qml, qwidget, qqmlapplicationengine, qquickview

I found a way to embed a QWidget in a QML, by using QQuickWidget render (anchoring, the QWidget with the QQuickWidget position), but I am trying to do the same using QQuickView/QmlApplicationEngine, which uses a different rendering system, and the QWidget is not shown.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QPushButton export to QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425885/qpushbutton-export-to-qml)

Comment: Currently it is not possible, previously the QML painting system was more compatible with Qt Widgets since it used QGraphicsScene but currently has another approach: Scene Graph.

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014415/qt5-embed-qwidget-object-in-qml

Answer (score 0):

None of the posts linked on the comments answered my question. There is this small work around (for those who need it):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine *engine = new QQmlApplicationEngine(&app);
    engine->load(QUrl("qrc:/qml/main.qml"));
    QQuickWindow* qmlwindow = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(engine->rootObjects().first());

    CustomWidget *customwidget = new CustomWidget();
    QWindow* customwidgetwindow = QWindow::fromWinId(customwidget->winId());

    customwidgetwindow->setParent(qmlwindow);
    customwidget->show();

    if (window) {
        QQuickItem *qmlCustomWidget = qmlwindow->findChild<QQuickItem*>("qmlcustomwidget");
        if (qmlCustomWidget) {
            new WidgetAnchor(customwidgetwindow, qmlCustomWidget);
        }
    }

return app.exec();
}
```

Where CustomWidget is QWidget based class, and WidgetAnchor.cpp is:

```
WidgetAnchor::WidgetAnchor(QWidget* pWidget, QQuickItem* pItem)
    : QObject(pWidget),
      _pWidget(pWidget),
      _pQuickItem(pItem)
{
    connect(_pQuickItem, &QQuickItem::xChanged, this, &WidgetAnchor::updateGeometry);
    connect(_pQuickItem, &QQuickItem::yChanged, this, &WidgetAnchor::updateGeometry);
    connect(_pQuickItem, &QQuickItem::widthChanged, this, &WidgetAnchor::updateGeometry);
    connect(_pQuickItem, &QQuickItem::heightChanged, this, &WidgetAnchor::updateGeometry);
    updateGeometry();
}

void WidgetAnchor::updateGeometry() {
    if (_pQuickItem) {
        QRectF r = _pQuickItem->mapRectToItem(nullptr, QRectF(_pQuickItem->x(), _pQuickItem->y(), _pQuickItem->width(), _pQuickItem->height()));
    _pWidget->setGeometry(r.toRect());
    }
}
```

And on main.qml you have:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 500; height: 500

    Item {
        objectName: "qmlcustomwidget"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: `new WidgetAnchor(customwidgetwindow, qmlCustomWidget);` Passing `QWindow*` to `QWidget*` is obviously wrong.

Comment: Is there any better approach you would suggest?

Comment: If only to let the code pass，it can be corrected like this `WindowAnchor(QWindow* pWindow, QQuickItem* pItem)`. Prioritize widget nesting qml by `qquickwidget`. A small number of widgets can be anchored by this. I just pointed out the details of your answer are wrong.